# Receiving error : ORA-01747 While trying to calculate COUNT(*) of a specific table

Tags: query, oracle-11g, plsql

Hope you're doing well.
I have two tables and as I far as I know for this scenario there is no need for their structures.

When I run this query :

```
SELECT COUNT(T.*) AS X
FROM table1 T INNER JOIN table2 M
     ON T.col1= M.col2
```

I receive this error:

```
ORA-01747:invalid user.table.column, table.column,or column specification
```

Is there something I'm missing here?? Dose this query have something which is against database rule?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not valid syntax.

```
SQL> select count(t.*) as x from dual t;
select count(t.*) as x from dual t
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification


SQL> select count(*) as x from dual t;

         X
----------
         1

SQL>
```